# regular expression repeating pattern

Tags: python, regex

I try to use regular expression to capture data group from below logs. The pattern is

```
<item> : <key> = <value> , <key> = <value>, ..., <key> = <value>
```

`([#\w\d]*?)[\s]*=[\s]*([.\w\d]*)` can capture group `<key>` and group `<value>`
but i want to capture the `<item>` group as well, so i group the above and repeat using {n}.

```
([\w]*):([\s]*(([#\w\d]*?)[\s]*=[\s]*([.\w\d]*)),*){1,}
```

> 20141207,07:15:52,0,>>RATIO: casher#=30,
>   Value=2.579,Units=ratio,Error=N 20141207,07:15:52,0,>>RATIO:
>   casher#=31, Value=4.509,Units=ratio,Error=N
>   20141207,07:15:52,0,>>RATIO: casher#=32,
>   Value=3.735,Units=ratio,Error=N 20141207,07:15:52,0,>>RATIO:
>   casher#=33, Value=2.401,Units=ratio,Error=N
>
> 20141207,07:15:52,0,>>CUSTOMER: casher#=30, Value=50,Units= count
>   20141207,07:15:52,0,>>CUSTOMER: casher#=31, Value=6,Units= count
>   20141207,07:15:52,0,>>CUSTOMER: casher#=32, Value=88,Units= count
>   20141207,07:15:52,0,>>CUSTOMER: casher#=33, Value=33,Units= count

[image: pic1]
[image]

obviously the result is not what is expecting. can anybody give me some tips? i am using python eventually to translate to code. thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but you can't capture _all_ `key=value` pairs with a single regex. Not in separate groups, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=>>)(\w+):|([\w#]+)\s*=\s*(\S+?)(?:,|\s)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/1

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >>                       '>>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                         more times (matching the most amount
                         possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |                        OR
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w#]+                   any character of: word characters (a-z,
                         A-Z, 0-9, _), '#' (1 or more times
                         (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                       more times (matching the most amount
                       possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                       more times (matching the most amount
                       possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+?                     non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                         and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                         least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                         end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```

Comment: i love you @vks, i am weak, would you please explain a little bit on the expression? thank you very much. i accepted the ans. thank you very much.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and teaching. your matching pattern also matched key=value even if the "item :" not exist, any advance technique to exclude those key = value line? anyway, your expression is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is a csv file, so you could make your life easier and use the csv module:

```
import csv

f = open('data.txt', 'rb')

for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
    if row:
        item, key_and_val = row[3].split(':')
        item = item[2:]
        key, val = key_and_val.split('=')

        print item
        print '    {} => {}'.format(key.strip(), val.strip())

        for key_and_val in row[4:]:
            key, val = key_and_val.split('=')
            print '    {} => {}'.format(key.strip(), val.strip())

--output:--
RATIO
    casher# => 30
    Value => 2.579
    Units => ratio
    Error => N
RATIO
    casher# => 31
    Value => 4.509
    Units => ratio
    Error => N
RATIO
    casher# => 32
    Value => 3.735
    Units => ratio
    Error => N
RATIO
    casher# => 33
    Value => 2.401
    Units => ratio
    Error => N
CUSTOMER
    casher# => 30
    Value => 50
    Units => count
CUSTOMER
    casher# => 31
    Value => 6
    Units => count
CUSTOMER
    casher# => 32
    Value => 88
    Units => count
CUSTOMER
    casher# => 33
    Value => 33
    Units => count
```

> your matching pattern also matched key=value even if the "item :" not
>   exist, any advance technique to **exclude those** key = value **line**?

The following will skip lines without an item:

```
for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
    if row:
        if row[3].startswith('>>'):  #Check if there is an item
            item, key_and_val = row[3].split(': ')
            item = item[2:]
            key, val = key_and_val.split('=')
            print item
            print '    {} => {}'.format(key.strip(), val.strip())

            for key_and_val in row[4:]:
                key, val = key_and_val.split('=')
                print '    {} => {}'.format(key.strip(), val.strip())

f.close()
```

Comment: thank you @7stud, i will use your code after extracted them to csv file. ^^"